# NullPointerException in Birt Reports

Tags: java, report, birt

I am very new to Birt Reports so bear me with this. I am getting

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.; nested exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

From some forums I came to know that there is some data source issue with such kind of errors but I am unable to resolve it. Please figure this out, if any one know such error.

#### here is the stack trace

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.internal.adapter.OdaDataSourceAdapter.(OdaDataSourceAdapter.java:85)
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.ModelAdapter.adaptDataSource(ModelAdapter.java:93)
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.defineCube(DataRequestSessi    onImpl.java:526)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.prepare(AbstractDataEngine.java:1    54)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.java:101)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedR    eportExecutor.java:59)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportEmitterExecutor.execute(Repor    tEmitterExecutor.java:76)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedR    eportExecutor.java:59)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.execute    (SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.java:51)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilde    r.java:193)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:228)
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:89)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1117)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.ja    va:146)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunRe    portActionHandler.java:78)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists    (BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters    (AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(Abstrac    tGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBase    ActionHandler.java:89)
```

org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(A    bstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
    org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(Ab    stractBaseComponentProcessor.java:159)
    org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumen    tProcessor.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(Abstract    BaseComponentProcessor.java:111)
    org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBi    ndingImpl.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispa    tcherServlet.java:225)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDisp    atcherServlet.java:112)
        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java    :290)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java    :235)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:347)
    org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:    583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

#### NOTE

I had Birt 2.3 version, and I am using ubuntu OS.

Comment: If it was working, then if broke, what did you do that made it breaK?  Do you have some reports that are broken, and some that work?

Comment: Actually the reports were developed by the contractors, and now as they are gone, I have no clue over it, as I am new and trying to understand the technologies using in the system.

Comment: Does the report use multiple data sets? Have you checked each individual one? You can do this by opening the data set and select "Preview results" in the menu on the left. If you get an error there, it's probably in the SQL of that data set.